# strange behaviour of Html.BeginForm

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, forms, post

lets create empty asp.net mvc 3 application.
code is

```
namespace MvcApplication1.Controllers
{
public class MyModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return Index1(new MyModel() {Id = 100});
    }
    public ActionResult Index1(MyModel model)
    {
        var nm = new MyModel();
        nm.Id = model.Id + 1;
        return View("test", nm);
    }
}
```

lets create shared view called test. View code is

```
@using MvcApplication1.Controllers
@model MyModel

@if (Model != null)
{
    using (Html.BeginForm("Index1", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { autocomplete = "off" }))
    {
    <div id="compareQuestions">
        <p>@Model.Id</p>
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Id)
        <input type="submit" value="save"/>
    </div>
    }
}
```

When we post form first time all is ok, but when it reloads after first post value in textbox incorrect. if we change this value and save post on controller we get model with the incorrect value, but not which we enter. How is this possible?

Comment: On the second post, is the hidden field's value 101? If not, what are the incorrect values, and what should be the correct values?

Comment: What is rendered by `<p>@Model.Id</p>`? What is rendered by `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)`? What about `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Id)`?

Comment: <p>@Model.Id</p> is 102 which is correct, @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id) and @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Id) is 101 which is incorrect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a significant difference between `<p>@Model.Id</p>` and `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)`.

When you POST the form, all POST'ed values are stored in `ModelState`.
When you use the `HtmlHelper` methods, they pull the value from `ModelState` first.  If `ModelState` doesn't contain a value, then it looks at the actual `m.Id`.

So, when you GET your form the first time, there is no `ModelState`.  But once you POST the form, it stores the values into `ModelState`, so the hidden input uses that value instead of `m.Id`.

If you want to ALWAYS use `m.Id`, then you need to clear the `ModelState` in your controller:

```
public ActionResult Index1(MyModel model)
{
    ModelState.Clear();
    ...
```

Comment: But actually why the implement it such way?

Comment: This is the mechanics of validation.  If you submit a form with invalid input, the ModelState holds that input, so that when you re-show the form, the fields are not blank.  For example, if my model requires an `int`, and you type `abc`, then the form is re-displayed with `abc` and an error message.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is the correct behavior, as you have written your action method. In the view, you are rendering both a text box and a hidden field for the same exact model property.

So when you increment the Id by 1 during the post, you are incrementing the value in the text box AND in the hidden field.

If you want the text box and hidden field to have DIFFERENT values after the second post, you need a different property on your model.

Another problem may be that, since you have 2 different `<input` elements with the same name, you can't be certain if the form will send the value from the hidden field or the text box. Again if these 2 fields should have different values, they need to be different properties on the model. If you want them to always be the same value, put either a TextBox or Hidden in the view -- but not both.

Comment: No, you do not understand question. Ofcourse it render the same value, but value is wrong.     <p>@Model.Id</p>
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id) have different value but they should have the same